# Jquery ajax request with slider

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider

I like to display results for my search form with ajax, it works great with text inputs but when it comes to sliders when I slide for example from 50 to 100, it sends a lot of requests but the thing is sometimes the request for 100 finishes before the request for 70 though the request for 100 has dispatched after the request for 70.

I can keep a variable and add it to the requests and increase that with every request and when an answer comes i can check if that is the answer for the most recent request but I don't want to introduce extra variables and work if there is a smarter way of handling this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `SetTimeout()`, and `ClearTimeout()` after each *Slider slide* event?

Something along the lines of this

```
var SlideTimeout;
//use the correct event handler, this is just to show you the concept
$(slider).slide(function(){
    ClearTimeout(SlideTimeout);
    SlideTimeout = SetTimeout(SliderSearchCallbackFunction, 400);
});
```

Basically your *Slider slide* event handler will reset a timeout each time the event is triggered. After 400 milliseconds (found in the second parameter of the `SetTimeout()` function in the example) of that event **not** being called, it will call the function `SliderSearchCallbackFunction`, thus only searching once it's apparent that the user is done sliding.

You can change the timeout to a time that you feel fits your script the best.